# React-router browserHistory throws error

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Using react-router 2.0.0 and trying to get the basics configured. Of course I want browser history because I don't want all that junk in the URL, so I read the docs and it seems super easy. This worked great when I used hashHistory, but switching to browserHistory not so much.

My app:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var browserHistory  = require('react-router').browserHistory;
var App = require('./components/App.react');
var About = require('./components/About');

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory } >
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path="about" component={About} />
        </Route>
    </Router>, 
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Here's the error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History':
>   A history state object with URL
>   'file:///E:/My%20Documents/GitHub/foo-bar/src/main/webapp/index.htm'
>   cannot be created in a document with origin 'null'.

From reading the error is sounds like the History API is complaining because the "origin" is null, but that's all down in the framework, so I'm not sure what to do.

I debugged into createBrowserHistory.js and found this is throwing the error:

```
  function getCurrentLocation(historyState) {
    historyState = historyState || window.history.state || {};

    var path = _DOMUtils.getWindowPath();
    var _historyState = historyState;
    var key = _historyState.key;

    var state = undefined;
    if (key) {
      state = _DOMStateStorage.readState(key);
    } else {
      state = null;
      key = history.createKey();

      //***********THIS LINE THROWS THE ERROR**************
      if (isSupported) window.history.replaceState(_extends({}, historyState, { key: key }), null, path);
    }

    var location = _PathUtils.parsePath(path);

    return history.createLocation(_extends({}, location, { state: state }), undefined, key);
  }
```

It seems like the issue is document.origin is null because I'm loading my index.htm from a file on my local machine rather than a remote server. I don't want to package and deploy my code every time just to test.

Comment: Yes, you need to run a server instead of using a `file://` URL. Webpack includes a dev server for this purpose. If you don't know how to set it up, look at pretty much any React tutorial, or use a React boilerplate like [react-slingshot](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot).

Comment: Will i get auto deployment and reload or do I need to go on a special quest for that

Comment: For a more general comment about BrowserHistory vs HashHistory please check out the store.js section @ http://spapas.github.io/2016/03/02/react-redux-tutorial/#store-js (hint: I propose to actually use HashHistory!)